# Prevent database (core data) sync to iCloud and backup to iTunes in iOS7.0

Tags: core-data, ios7, icloud

How can i prevent database (core data) sync to iCloud and backup to iTunes in iOS7
Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just never call `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier`.